# Invalid WatchKit Support - The expected app is missing from the app’s root location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

After searching, I couldn't find an answer to this exact issue.  When I upload my app's build to iTunes Connect using Xcode 8 (GM Seed), it says that the build was uploaded.  Then, I get an email with this (The app's name is not AppName, it's just a placeholder):

> Invalid WatchKit Support - The expected app is missing from the app’s root location, such as /Payload/AppName.app/Watch.

I have changed provisioning profiles, but it didn't do anything.

How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you upload your app with Fastlane ?

Comment: Did you found any solution regarding this ?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper no